# If I bridge a WiFi card to an ethernet card, then I connect another computer to the ethernet adapter is the router aware of this?

Tags: wireless-networking, lan, bridge, isp

I have an ISP that only allows me to add seven computers to the wireless network, I have to call them and give them the computer MAC address.

I have a computer that isn't authorized, and I have a computer that is authorized and have both an ethernet and a WLAN card.

I'm in Windows 7, and I bridged both cards. When I connect the unauthorized computer to the authorized computer, the unauthorized computer doesn't connect.

Is the router receiving the MAC of the other computer and not authorizing it? Do I have to configure something else?

Comment: What a ridiculous restriction, I'd switch providers ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

Your ISP is probably using MAC whitelisting for network connection, which is actually very unsafe way to do filtering.

Anyway, the router will be able to get the MAC address of the second computer, but it should not trigger MAC filtering on the WiFi access controls. Still, if the router is doing some more checks, it could be easily detected.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best you can do is not bridging the interfaces and to configure internet connection sharing on the "server" machine (or some other kind of NAT).

Comment: What you want here is to use ICS (if on windows) instead of bridging. Bridging says "These two connectors go to the same network, so use them both", not "pass traffic from interface A to interface B"